# How can I filter my dataframe based on groupby+nlargest result?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with all Fifa 19 players. I've used *group by* to get the top 10 countries with the best players (best as in the highest overall mean), including only countries with more than 250 players in the Dataframe.

```
df[df.groupby('Nationality')['Overall'].transform('size') > 250].groupby(['Nationality'])['Overall'].mean().nlargest(10)
```

Now, I want to get the entire dataframe, all columns included, but only with these top 10 countries. How can I do this?

UPDATE:

Example created to better illustrate:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice','Rick'], 
               'income': [40000, 50000, 42000, 10000],
              'country':['Brazil','USA','Brazil','Canada']})

df[df.groupby('country')['income'].transform('size') > 1].groupby(['country'])['income'].mean().nlargest(2)
```

I would like to filter only brazil on this dataframe

Comment: why not create a sample example so we can replicate this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Sorry about that @anky_91. I thought it wasn't necessary. I will do this.

Comment: Never think that, think about the users who will look up to this post in near future. This won't help them. :) Hope you understand what I mean. Glad you are willing to create an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the values of `country` in your "top N" dataframe to subset the original dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice','Rick'], 
               'income': [40000, 50000, 42000, 10000],
              'country':['Brazil','USA','Brazil','Canada']})

top = df[df.groupby('country')['income'].transform('size') > 1].groupby(['country'])['income'].mean().nlargest(2)

df_top = df.loc[df['country'].isin(top.reset_index()['country'])]
```